# Is it possible logging another GUI in the QThread

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qthread, pyqtgraph

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import pyqtgraph as pg
import logging
import threading

from tqdm import tqdm
import time

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.plot_widget = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.plot_widget)
        self.plot_data = None
        self.setupPlotLogger(self.plot_widget)
        threading.Thread(target=self.foo).start()
        
    def foo(self):
        for i in tqdm(range(100)):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            logging.getLogger('test').debug(i)
    
        
    def setupPlotLogger(self, widget):
        pl = PlotLogger()
        pl.comp = widget
        pl.data = self.plot_data
        logging.getLogger('test').setLevel(level=logging.DEBUG)
        logging.getLogger('test').addHandler(pl)

    def do_task(self, value):
        logging.getLogger('test').info(value)


class PlotLogger(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        record = float(self.format(record))
        
        if self.data is not None:
            self.data.append(record)
        else:
            self.data = [record]
            
        self.comp.plot(self.data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

In above code, I have got warning message which is "QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread".

In this case, I wanna logging another gui component(PlotWidget) while thread something.

what i searching is the problem is call another UI component(might be PlotWidget).

Is there solution for what i want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Although it might be look funny, i was findout solution myself.
so, i am shared how can i solve this problem.

the key thing is using 'invokeMethod',

```py
    # make some slot function for invokeMethod
    @QtCore.Slot(str)
    def test(self, value):
        logging.getLogger('test').info(float(value))
            
    def foo(self):
        for i in tqdm(range(100)):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            # call invokeMethod
            QtCore.QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self,
                                            "test", 
                                            QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection, 
                                            QtCore.Q_ARG(str, str(i)))
```

Comment: The problem has absolutely nothing to do with logging, but with the fact that widgets are not thread safe and should **never** be accessed from other threads. If you need to do inter thread communication, the *correct* way to do so is to use QThread and signals.